# run openai gym with google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I was trying to run the CartPole-v0 example on a Google Compute Engine VM.
https://gym.openai.com/docs

```
import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()
for _ in range(1000):
    env.render()
    env.step(env.action_space.sample()) # take a random action
```

I have XQuartz installed, and ssh with -X.

First, I was getting 
pyglet.canvas.xlib.NoSuchDisplayException: Cannot connect to "None"

Then according to http://www.gitterforum.com/discussion/openai-gym?page=28, I use "xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 1400x900x24" /bin/bash"

Then it ran fine with the result:

```
Making new env: CartPole-v0
You are calling 'step()' even though this environment has already returned done = True. You should always call 'reset()' once you receive 'done = True' -- any further steps are undefined behavior
```

But there is nothing rendered...

Answer (score 2):

Use code from Observations section on https://gym.openai.com/docs.