# openAi-gym NameError

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openai-gym

I am trying to use the famous 'Gym' module from OpenAI on WSL and executing code on python 3.5.2.
When I try to run an environment [as explained here](https://gym.openai.com/docs), using the code:

```
import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
for i_episode in range(20):
    observation = env.reset()
    for t in range(100):
        env.render()
        print(observation)
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        if done:
            print("Episode finished after {} timesteps".format(t+1))
            break
```

this happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/home/DrHofstadter/gym/gym/core.py", line 153, in render
    return self._render(mode=mode, close=close)
  File "/home/DrHofstadter/gym/gym/core.py", line 285, in _render
    return self.env.render(mode, close)
  File "/home/DrHofstadter/gym/gym/core.py", line 153, in render
    return self._render(mode=mode, close=close)
  File "/home/DrHofstadter/gym/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py", line 114, in _render
    from gym.envs.classic_control import rendering
  File "/home/DrHofstadter/gym/gym/envs/classic_control/rendering.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pyglet.gl import *
  File "/home/DrHofstadter/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 224, in <module>
    del base
NameError: name 'base' is not defined
```

The problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40036512/run-openai-gym-with-google-compute-engine)
nothing is being rendered. (The gitterforum link given in question doesn't work anymore.)

Comment: Are you running on a remote server?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a perfect answer to this question but this is my experience how I resolved this problem.

I was getting the same error when I running my programme from the spyder. but when **I execute the same code from the terminal it didn't throw any error**. 
but make your locale is correctly configured for the gym environment.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
git clone https://github.com/openai/gym.git
cd gym
pip install -e .
```

Or,

```
pip install pyglet
```

Answer (score 1):

Please show us pyglet and gym versions and we can compare them. You can delete all gym and after reinstall with `pip install 'gym[all]'`. Additionally, if you work on Colab or Jupyter you can add a display like below ( I think you work on a notebook)
you can add some supports like **xvfb** and **opengl** for the support virtual display.
If you use Linux basically install with

```
apt-get install -y xvfb python-opengl > /dev/null 2>&1
pip install gym pyvirtualdisplay > /dev/null 2>&1
```

after that, you must change your code like below format

**Libraries**

```
import gym
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import display as ipythondisplay
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
```

**Started virtual display**

```
display = Display(visible=0, size=(400, 300))
display.start()
```

Now Finish move

```
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
for i_episode in range(20):
   observation = env.reset()
   for t in range(100):
      plt.imshow(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))# CHANGED
      ipythondisplay.clear_output(wait=True) # ADDED
      ipythondisplay.display(plt.gcf()) # ADDED
      print(observation)
      action = env.action_space.sample()
      observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
      if done:
         print("Episode finished after {} timesteps".format(t+1))
         break
```