# ImportError: Library "GLU" not found and Error occurred while running `from pyglet.gl import *`

Tags: python, opengl, reinforcement-learning, pyglet

I am trying Atari Breakout game. It looks like it [does not work well with Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49203023/openai-gym-nameerror-in-google-colaboratory) and [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605769/openai-gym-atari-on-windows). Working on school cloud.

```
import gym
# Create environment
env = gym.make("BreakoutDeterministic-v4")
env.action_space  # actions are integers from 0 to 3

env.reset()
done = False
score = 0
rewards=[]
while not done:
    action = random.randrange(env.action_space.n)  # select random action
    obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)     # make action and get results
    rewards.append(reward)
    score += reward
    env.render()
    time.sleep(0.01)

env.close()
print('Score =', score)
plt.plot(rewards)
```

Get common errors and searched for resolution:

```
ImportError: Library "GLU" not found.

Error occurred while running `from pyglet.gl import *`
HINT: make sure you have OpenGL install. On Ubuntu, you can run 'apt-get install python-opengl'.
If you're running on a server, you may need a virtual frame buffer; something like this should work:
'xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 1400x900x24" python <your_script.py>'
```

- [Official thread](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/2101) did not help
- [Tried multiple SO solutions here](https://www.google.com/search?q=Error%20occurred%20while%20running%20%60from%20pyglet.gl%20import%20*%60%20HINT%3A%20make%20sure%20you%20have%20OpenGL%20install.%20On%20Ubuntu%2C%20you%20can%20run%20%27apt-get%20install%20python-opengl%27.%20If%20you%27re%20running%20on%20a%20server%2C%20you%20may%20need%20a%20virtual%20frame%20buffer%3B%20something%20like%20this%20should%20work%3A%20%27xvfb-run%20-s%20%22-screen%200%201400x900x24%22%20python%20%3Cyour_script.py%3E%27&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS891US891&oq=Error%20occurred%20while%20running%20%60from%20pyglet.gl%20import%20*%60%20HINT%3A%20make%20sure%20you%20have%20OpenGL%20install.%20On%20Ubuntu%2C%20you%20can%20run%20%27apt-get%20install%20python-opengl%27.%20If%20you%27re%20running%20on%20a%20server%2C%20you%20may%20need%20a%20virtual%20frame%20buffer%3B%20something%20like%20this%20should%20work%3A%20%27xvfb-run%20-s%20%22-screen%200%201400x900x24%22%20python%20%3Cyour_script.py%3E%27&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.317j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Tried so far different options, which I found online

- !pip install gym
- !pip install -f https://github.com/Kojoley/atari-py/releases atari_py
- !pip install gym[atari]
- !pip install git+https://github.com/Kojoley/atari-py.git
- !pip install pyglet==1.5.11